# How do I adjust the Microsoft Small Business Server email spam protection filters?

Tags: spam, windows-sbs

How can I get the Exchange in SBS to be less strict in filtering spam?
Most clients emails go directly into the spam folder.

Comment: What version of Windows Small Business Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Exchange version you are using. SBS 2011 uses Exchange 2010, SBS 2008 uses Exchange 2007 and SBS 2003 uses Exchange 2003.

#### Exchange 2010

Setting the "SCL Junk Threshold" parameter for one of the *Junk/Quarantine/Reject/Delete* actions will influence your filter's sensibility either organization-wide

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -SCL[Junk|Quarantine|Reject|Delete]Threshold <Value 1-10>
```

or user-specific

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity John -AntispamBypassEnabled $true -SCL[Junk|Quarantine|Reject|Delete]Enabled $true -SCLJunkThreshold <Value 1-10>
```

The SCL is the "Spam Confidence Level" calculated by Exchange anti-spam modules - the higher you set the threshold, the less sensitive your filter will be. Note that you have rather limited possibilities to influence the SCL calculation itself. See the [Technet docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123559.aspx) for details.

#### Echange 2007

pretty much the same thing as Exchange 2010, but without the ability for user-specific configurations. The organization-wide setting can be done with

```
Set-ContentFilterConfig -SCL[Reject|Delete|Quarantine]Enabled $true -SCLQuarantineThreshold <Value 1-10>
```

[Technet docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995995%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for details again.

#### Exchange 2003 SP2

Basically, only the "Block threshold" is available and configurable either through the Exchange System Manager or the [AD ms-Exch-Uce-Block-Threshold attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998841).